# How to run .exe binary of a remote server on the remote server from a c++ application in windows platform

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

What are the ways to run  .exe binary of a remote server on the remote server from a c++ application in windows platform??

Answer (score 1):

Open a telnet session to the server, start binary.

Answer (score 0):

open a telnet session (like MSalters suggests), or write a small server app that will run on the remote server, and listen for your its mother application's request to run that ".exe binary".

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing sounds exactly like what [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) already does.  So you could either shell out to that or re-implement how it works.  There are some descriptions of what it actually does:

http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/42919/psexec.html (I believe I read this in the past, but it's behind a paywall now)

http://www.ntkernel.com/w&p.php?id=15

Comment: Both links are dead as of this post's timestamp.